# how can I sort an array by the number of repetitions of an array element

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

For example i have an array {1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,}
I need to transform it into {4,4,4,4,4,,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1}
So i have to sort it by the number of repetitions of an array element somehow.
I saw some solves of this problem on c++ but i have to write it on C.
I can`t use vector or smth. Just Sorting with buffer array or inside of exact array.

I tried something like this, but honestly now i etched into a dead end:
It is dont work properly as i ment.
I have an algoritm in my head:

1. Program count how times some element was repeated and write in into a second array
2. Program sort second array
3. Program sort first array by second array somehow

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    int A[size], B[size];
    int counter1, counter2 = -1;
    int temp = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Enter %d element of array: ", i + 1);
        scanf_s("%d", &A[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
        counter1 = 0;
        counter2++;
        for (int j = i; j < size; j++) {
            if (A[j] == A[j - 1]) {
                break;
            }
            if (A[j] == A[j+1]) {
                counter1++;
                B[counter2] = counter1;
                temp = A[i];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("El %d = %d\n",i+1,B[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: A naive algorithm would be: search for longest sequence. When found, copy to the beginning of a new array. Search for the next sequence with the same length, copy if found, then search for sequence length-1, copy if found... down to zero. Not the most efficient but gets the expected result.

Comment: Do you know the max values possible for array elements? Can the max value be large? If  it's small, then you could create an array that uses the element value as index. which acts as an element counter. So e.g. you do `Counters[A[index]]++`. Once you have collected the count of each element, you can do the sorting by checking this `Counters` array.

Comment: consecutive repetitions or also like this (2 is repeated 4 time) `{1,2,3,5,7,2,4,2,5,3,2,3,4,3,9,7,3}` ?

Comment: Like your variant also

Comment: The task isn't difficult. So, I suggest you practise a bit more. There are multiple methods. Although, I can give some tips on how to solve this issue (the easiest one). 
Run a for loop to compare each data with every other data. And then, with a simple comparison, swap the data.
If both the data are equal, then don't swap.

Comment: I have a lot of problems like this but i don`t know how to sort by times of repetition. And that is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best, but it does the job! I'm storing the final result in the `Result[len][2];` variable! you can modify the code as you like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( )
{  
    int array[] = {1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,11,10,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,};
    int i,j,k=0,l,len,flag=0,temp0, temp1;
    len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    int Result[len][2];
    memset(Result,0,sizeof(Result));

    for (i = 0 ;i < len ; i++ )
    {       
        if (k != 0)
        {
            for (l= 0 ;l < k ; l++ )
            if (array[i]== Result[l][0]) goto skip;    
        }
        for(j= i ; j < len ; j++ )                
        {  
            if (array[i] == array[j])
            {                
                Result[k][0] = array[j];  
                Result[k][1]++;flag = 1;
            }
        }   
        skip: if (flag == 1) {k++; flag = 0;}
    }

     for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
     {
         for(j= i+1 ; j < k ; j++ )        
         {
             if(Result[i][1] < Result[j][1])
               {   
                   temp0  = Result[i][0];
                   temp1  = Result[i][1]; 
                   Result[i][0] = Result[j][0];
                   Result[i][1] = Result[j][1];                   
                   Result[j][0]  = temp0 ;
                   Result[j][1]  = temp1 ;                   
               }
         }
     }

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) printf("[%d][%d]\n",Result[i][0],Result[i][1]);     

    return 0;
}
```

The output at my computer under the Linux environment is as follows:

```
[6][12]
[4][5]
[3][4]
[2][3]
[11][1]
[10][1]
[1][1]
```

Comment: Oh god! U are the best. Thanks, you saved me!

Comment: I didn't have time to put comments! But I hope you understand what I was doing in the above code. That is more important.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I sort an array by the number of repetitions

1. Sort array `A` of size `m` by value .
2. Walk array and count number of different values: `n`
3. Allocate array `B[]` of size `n` of `struct`s that has 2 members: value and occurrence.
4. Walk array `A[]` again and populate `B[]`
5. Sort `B[]` by `.occurrence`.
6. Walk `B[]` and re-populate `A[]`.

O(m) memory, O(m *log m) time.